# Disable css rules in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to put a small web inside a html template. The html template has it own css rules. One of the parent css rule is the following:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif!important;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  letter-spacing: -0.4em!important;
}
```

I don't control that css file, so I need to remove/neutralize that three rules programmatically when it's loaded. Is there any way to do it How can I do that with jquery?

I try this, without success:

```
$('*').css('font-family', '');
$('*').css('color', '');
$('*').css('letter-spacing', '');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can always apply inline css which will override the given css.

Comment: $('<style>* { }</style>').appendTo('body'); will do the trick.

Comment: Why not just override them in a stylesheet you control? by doing it using jquery it is going to be very poor on performance as you are literally applying inline style to every element

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst how this will do the trick ? this won't  affect the CSS file

Comment: You can't "neutralise" them, as you say. You can overwrite them with more specific styles (my preference would be written to an inline style block, as Jasper Seinhorst suggested), but there's no way to, e.g., "reset" the values so that your own CSS will take precedence, if that's your question. Essentially ALL of your overriding CSS would need to be set via JavaScript.

Comment: Also have you thuoght about using an iframe, that way the inner page won't affect the outer page

Comment: If you don't own , just contact the owner . It is bad performance that control css by jQuery

Comment: like delinear said, you cant neutralize that styles for your whole page. maybe it's better to create a neuralize class (with !important) and add them to the specific div.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery to add a style rule (as prescribed in the comments already) that sets each style you want to override to `initial`

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this, because in your css file you have `!important`.

```
 $( '.someclass' ).each(function () {
        this.style.setProperty( 'font-family', 'serif', 'important' );
    });
```

Comment: Probably should not be explicitly setting the rule values, since different browser user style sheets may have different values by default. Better to use 'initial' to always select the browser default instead